# Finding the image of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let B = {$1, x, x^2, x^3$} denote the standard basis of $P_3(F)$. Suppose $T \in L(P_3(F))$, where
$T(1)=1+x+x^2 +x^3, T(x)=1+x−2x^3, T(x^2)=x^3, T(x^3)=1+x+x^2$.

1. Find the matrix that represents T with respect to B.
2. Find the kernel of T.
3. Find the image of T.

What I tried:

Clearly, Mat [T,B] has (1,1,1,1) as its first column, (1,1,0,-2) as its 2nd column, (0,0,1,0) as its 3rd and (1,1,1,0) as its 4th column.

To find ker T, I took $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ and plugged T(p(x))=0, solved the system of equations to get $a_0=-a_3,a_1=0,a_2=a_3$. So, Ker T = Span {$-1+x^2+x^3$}. I am not sure how to go about finding the image of T. Also, can we use the matrix here? I tried finding the linear combination of its columns but don't we specifically need the range T to be a subspace if $P_3(F)$?

I am slightly all over the place here, so I apologize if this seems very silly!

Comment: The question ‘find the image of $T$’ kind of vague because you could say it is $\operatorname{span}(\{T(1),T(x),T(x^2),T((x^3)\})$ and this would be technically correct (but not particularly informative)

Comment: What it is probably wanting you to do is find a basis for the image. Since the dimension of the kernel is 1, the rank-nullity theorem implies that the dim of the image is 3. Hence, pick any three of $T(1),T(x),T(x^2),T(x^3)$ and you this forms a basis

Comment: $T(1-x^3)= x^3$, so your calculation of $\ker T$ is mistaken.  The third column should be $(0~0~0~1)$, not $(0~0~1~0)$.  I think you actually want $\ker (T) = \operatorname{span} (\{ 1-x^2-x^3 \})$.

Comment: @JackT That's actually not correct because $\{T(1), T(x^2), T(x^3) \}$ is linearly dependent.  You need to choose $T(x)$ along with the image of two other basis elements.

Comment: @RobertShore Oh you are right, I just recalculated and edited Ker T.

Comment: So to find the image of T, we find which one of {T(1),T(x),T(x^2),T(x^3)} is linearly dependent on the others, and then take a span of the rest?

Comment: No, because any set of four vectors in the image is necessarily linearly dependent.  You just need to confirm that you've found a set of three vectors in the image that is linearly independent.  Any suitable choice of three vectors will work, but you do need to confirm that it works.

Comment: I get it now, thanks!